# How can we listen to multiple topics in same Kafka consumer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to have multiple topics in same kafka consumer configuration.
I tried the following options but it didn't work.

With
`ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties(gatewayPropertyConfigurer.getProperty("topic","topic1);`

created a separate `containerproperty` for `topic1`.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: which framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what framework you are using, but the basic `KafkaConsumer` Java class has a `subscribe` method that you should look into using.

You only need different properties for different consumers if you really do have different consumer properties. For example, if are fine with the defaults and both topics have the same serialization settings, you only need one set of properties.